# If "match" else

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In XSLT I often match nodes using the following command

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'Proposal']/*[local-name() = 'ApplicationData']">
```

which would get the nodes from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xfa generator="XFA2_4" APIVersion="2.8.9029.0"?>
    <xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/" timeStamp="2013-03-01T09:48:58Z" uuid="3e3468da-104d-4532-8077-0dc001ca166b">
       <xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
          <xfa:data>
             <Proposal xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/planning/OneAppProposal-2006" Version="">
                 <oneapp:ApplicationData xmlns:oneapp="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/planning/OneAppProposal-2006">
                        <oneapp:TreesHedgesWales/>
                        <oneapp:OtherLowCarbonEnergy/>
                 </oneapp:ApplicationData>
             </Proposal>
         ...
```

matching

```
<oneapp:ApplicationData xmlns:oneapp="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/planning/OneAppProposal-2006">
      <oneapp:TreesHedgesWales/>
      <oneapp:OtherLowCarbonEnergy/>
 </oneapp:ApplicationData>
```

How could I determine whether `ApplicationData` existed, and if not, insert it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Insert it where? And from where? -- BTW, why don't you use the given namespaces, instead of the horrible hack of `*[local-name() = 'xyz']`?

Comment: Insert it into the XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the logic to a template that matched the 'Proposal' element

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'Proposal']">
```

Then, you would just write an `xsl:if` statement, like so:

```
<xsl:if test="not(*[local-name() = 'ApplicationData'])">
   <oneapp:ApplicationData xmlns:oneapp="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/planning/OneAppProposal-2006">
      <oneapp:TreesHedgesWales/>
      <oneapp:OtherLowCarbonEnergy/>
   </oneapp:ApplicationData>
</xsl:if>
```

You would need to wrap this in an `xsl:copy` if you wanted to retain the `Proposal` element.

If you didn't already have an existing template matching `Proposal` in your XSLT, you could add the test to template match itself

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'Proposal'][not(*[local-name() = 'ApplicationData'])]">
   <xsl:copy>
      <oneapp:ApplicationData xmlns:oneapp="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/planning/OneAppProposal-2006">
          <oneapp:TreesHedgesWales/>
          <oneapp:OtherLowCarbonEnergy/>
      </oneapp:ApplicationData>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As michael.hor257k mentioned in comments, it would be much cleaner if you declared your namespaces in your XSLT, and used namespace prefixes in the matching....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
     xmlns:oneapp="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/planning/OneAppProposal-2006">

<xsl:template match="oneapp:Proposal[not(oneapp:ApplicationData)]">
   <xsl:copy>
      <oneapp:ApplicationData>
         <oneapp:TreesHedgesWales/>
         <oneapp:OtherLowCarbonEnergy/>
      </oneapp:ApplicationData>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```